# How to calculate the Avogadro constant from the Loschmidt constant and ideal gas law?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, physical-constants

Josef Loschmidt use Kinetic Molecular Theory and calculate  number density, now I want to use number density in law gas to calculate Avogadro constant:

$PV = nRT$

number density $= n/V$

$V = n/$number density

so I  have $\rightarrow P = \text{number density}\times RT $

BUT  in Wikipedia it says:

$n_0=\frac{p_0N_\mathrm A}{RT_0}$

from where does "Avogadro constant" come from in this formula?

Answer (score 0):

The constant $R$ is the *molar* gas constant.  In your formula, $n$ is the amount of gas measured in moles, and $n/V$ is the molar density.

To convert between the number of moles and the number of particles, you use the Avogadro constant, $N_A=6\times 10^{23}\text{ particles/mole}$.  The *number* density is $N_A n/V$.

Comment: Please note that the quantity “amount of substance” shall not be called “number of moles”, just as the quantity “mass” shall not be called “number of kilograms”.

Comment: thanks ,   Amedeo Avogadro present the ideal law gas before the conception of mole yet been discovered so how the R  is the molar gas constant . I mean what did he use for R Units.

Comment: @johnnyishere, the value of "R", and it's units, depend on what units are selected for "P", "V", and "T".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant